# AutoIT How to encrypt a single file

Tags: arrays, encryption, autoit

So here's my current code:

```
Local $source = "C:\Users\EXAMPLE\Documents\EXAMPLE"
Local $password = "Example"

Local $array = _FileListToArrayRec($source, "*", 1, , 1, 2); LOADS ALL FILES FROM $source AS AN ARRAY
```

I don't know how to continue from there because what I want to do is take all of the files in that array and encrypt them all. But that's where another problem arises, how do I encrypt all of the files and save them in the SAME LOCATION?

Example: `_Crypt_EncryptFile($sSourceFile, $sDestinationFile, $vCryptKey, $iALG_ID)` takes a file and saves the unencrypted version to another location, how do I make it so that it overrides the original file with the encrypted version? I'm VERY stumped here and have Googled multiple subjects and can't find anything that would help me, so I came here hoping I could find my answer. Anyways thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to cycle through the array entries in a loop. For each file you just call the encrypt-function. Did you try to use the same destination as the source? If this won't work, you should encrypt it to your `@TempDir` and afterwards use `FileMove(..., ..., 1)` to overwrite your source file with your encrypted one. You should check for it's consistency before...

Comment: By the way, there is a comma and other parameters too much in your parameter list... `_FileListToArray($sPath [, $sFilter = "*" [, $iFlag = 0]])` just takes three parameters. And the `$iFlag` sets whether to return files, folders or both (default).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <Crypt.au3>
#include <File.au3>

Local $sSource = "C:\Users\EXAMPLE\Documents\EXAMPLE"
Local $sPassword = "Example"

Local $aArray = _FileListToArrayRec($sSource, "*", 1, 1, 1, 2); LOADS ALL FILES FROM $sSource AS AN ARRAY AND AS A FULLPATH
If Not @error Then
    For $i = 1 To $aArray[0]
        If Not _Crypt_EncryptFile($aArray[$i], $aArray[$i], $sPassword, $CALG_AES_256) Then
            ConsoleWrite("Error: " & @error & ", " & $aArray[$i] & @CRLF)
        EndIf
    Next
EndIf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need file encryption for AutoIt consider the solution listed here

https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/178131-autoit-string-files-encryption/

It uses polymorphic (random) encryption on the file and generates the output code in AutoIt with the file contents encrypted:

```
; encrypted with https://www.stringencrypt.com (v1.0.0) [AutoIt]
#include <Array.au3>

; $Label = "Fast & easy AutoIt string and file encryption."
Global $Label[47] = [ 0xC254, 0xC273, 0xC261, 0xC260, 0xC212, 0xC236, 0xC202, 0xC24B, _
                      0xC253, 0xC281, 0xC277, 0xC20C, 0xC22B, 0xC277, 0xC27E, 0xC27D, _
                      0xC21B, 0xC280, 0xC22A, 0xC281, 0xC27E, 0xC25A, 0xC237, 0xC232, _
                      0xC255, 0xC21C, 0xC24F, 0xC22A, 0xC24E, 0xC214, 0xC248, 0xC247, _
                      0xC23E, 0xC237, 0x3E0A, 0xC233, 0xC234, 0xC251, 0xC27C, 0xC227, _
                      0xC282, 0xC280, 0xC247, 0xC27D, 0xC224, 0xC23E, 0x3D92 ];

For $SYdIB = 0 to 46
    $fWyHA = $Label[$SYdIB];
    $fWyHA += $SYdIB;
    $fWyHA = BitNOT($fWyHA);
    $fWyHA = BitXOR($fWyHA, $SYdIB);
    $fWyHA += $SYdIB;
    $fWyHA -= $SYdIB;
    $fWyHA = BitXOR($fWyHA, $SYdIB);
    $fWyHA = $fWyHA - 1;
    $fWyHA = BitXOR($fWyHA, $SYdIB);
    $fWyHA = $fWyHA + 1;
    $fWyHA += $SYdIB;
    $fWyHA = BitXOR($fWyHA, 0xC212);
    $fWyHA = BitNOT($fWyHA);
    $fWyHA += $SYdIB;
    $Label[$SYdIB] = ChrW(BitAND($fWyHA, 0xFFFF));
Next

$Label = _ArrayToString($Label, "")

ConsoleWrite($Label);
```

It's also pretty hard to overcome by deobfuscators because of the complex and random decryption code.